# Photo Downloader for Facebook/Instagram

Tags: gratis, images, download-manager, facebook, instagram

I'm looking for software/web tools that can download all the photos on a web page, and particularly ones that work well with Facebook and Instagram (Twitter is a plus, too - if you can point me to something that offers a gallery view of @someone's Twitter photos, even better).

I've seen plenty of tools that let you download all your photos. I've also seen a ton of browser extensions that don't work well or at all, and tried a few bookmarklets. (I'd provide a list of tools I've tried if I could remember all of the names.)  An acceptable solution:

- Can be triggered from the web browser (or another tool if logged in.).
- Downloads all photos on the page, but lets you pick ones you don't want.
- Can obtain images weather they use img HTML tags directly, or embed the picture as a background on a div or other element.
- Lets you choose the download directory (zip or individual is acceptable).
- Doesn't have a very messy user interface.

(The more you can match, the better.)
Acceptable OS is Windows 10 or Ubuntu.

Edit: I'm going to start adding a list of things that DON'T work, or don't work well enough. So that people know I've ruled them out.

- http://saveallimages.com/ might do what I need, but it's membership requirement limits it's functionality, even with the browser extension.
- [Facebook Album and Photo Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/facebook-album-photo-mana/lgiedegfmekolcplboelnmfoiefpcpfg/related?utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher) Only downloads your photos.
- [PhotoLive](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/photolive-download-facebo/fpjnpabklnaaifclgealaepelncljadk?utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher) just doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

[Download FB Album Mod](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/download-fb-album-mod/cgjnhhjpfcdhbhlcmmjppicjmgfkppok?hl=en) seems to work. Must have missed this one last time I went hunting for this kind of software.

Answer (score 0):

#### [gallery-dl](https://github.com/mikf/gallery-dl)

[gallery-dl](https://github.com/mikf/gallery-dl) is a powerful and versatile command-line tool that can download images and videos from various websites, including Instagram and Twitter. It supports a wide range of options and features to customize your downloads, such as filtering, naming, authentication, and more. However, it does not work with Facebook as of now.

To install gallery-dl, you need to have [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/) installed on your computer, or you can download the [standalone executable file](https://github.com/mikf/gallery-dl#user-content-installation).

To use gallery-dl, you need to run it from a terminal or command prompt with a command like this:

```
gallery-dl --dest "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads" --cookies-from-browser "Firefox" https://www.instagram.com/exampleusername
```

This will download all the media from the given Instagram profile URL to the specified destination folder. It will use the cookies from your Firefox browser to access the profile. You can change the browser by modifying the `--cookies-from-browser` option. You can also change the download folder by modifying the `--dest` option. If you want to download from Twitter instead of Instagram, just use a Twitter profile URL in the command. The downloaded media will be sorted in subfolders according to the website and username. For the above example, the media from “exampleusername” on Instagram will be in `C:\Users\[Windows username]\Downloads\instagram\exampleusername`.

Let’s see how gallery-dl meets your requirements:

> Can be triggered from the web browser (or another tool if logged in.).

Since gallery-dl is a command-line tool, you cannot trigger it from the web browser directly. However, you can simply copy the URL of the page you want to download and paste it into the command line. Alternatively, you can use your browser cookies to authenticate gallery-dl and access private or restricted content. See the [documentation](https://github.com/mikf/gallery-dl#documentation) for more details.

> Downloads all photos on the page, but lets you pick ones you don't want.

gallery-dl has many options to filter and select the media you want to download. You can use keywords, ranges, patterns, sizes, dates, and more to specify what you are looking for. See the [documentation](https://github.com/mikf/gallery-dl#documentation) for more details.

> Can obtain images weather they use img HTML tags directly, or embed the picture as a background on a div or other element.

I believe it can download media regardless of the above factors, provided that you have access to those posts.

> Lets you choose the download directory (zip or individual is acceptable).

You can choose the download directory by using the `--dest` option, as shown above. If you want to download the media as a zip file, you can use the `--zip` option.

> Doesn't have a very messy user interface.

gallery-dl has a simple and clean user interface, as it only shows the essential information and progress of the downloads.

> Acceptable OS is Windows 10 or Ubuntu.

gallery-dl works on Windows, Linux, and MacOS.